# pdo database abstraction

Tags: php, syntax, pdo

Can someone help me to see what is going wrong with this setup

I build the @sql query in the function below like this.
The extra quotes are setup in the conditions array.

```
        $sql .= " WHERE $field = \"$value\"";
```

The pdo update function loops the conditions array like this.

```
if (!is_null($conditions))
{
$cond = ' WHERE';
$obj = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($conditions));
foreach($obj as $k=>$v)
{
    $cond .= " $k=$v";
    $cond .= $obj->hasNext() ? ' AND' : '';
}
}
```

My point to make is that I can not build arrays with values without adding slashes for quotation marks around the values.
Otherwise the sql error that is being thrown is that it is an unknown column.

Is there something other that I can do?

Could someone give me some input on this please.

**edit: the rest off the update function**

Where could I bind the values of the conditions array and have them
executed also? As I am seeing it now, only the values array is executed?
Do I need to loop both arrays and then merge both arrays?

```
$obj = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($values));

            $db = db::getInstance();
            $sql = "UPDATE $table SET \n";
            foreach( $obj as $field=>$val)
            {
                $sql .= "$field= :$field";
                $sql .= $obj->hasNext() ? ',' : '';
                $sql .= "\n";
            }

            $sql .= $cond ; 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

            // bind de params
            foreach($values as $k=>$v)
            {
                $stmt->bindParam(':'.$k, $v);
            }


            $stmt->execute($values );
```

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `addslashes()`.  It's an inadequate way to escape values, and has known security bugs.

Double-quotes in standard SQL are for delimited identifiers.  Use single-quotes for string literals.

MySQL's default mode allows you to use single-quotes and double-quotes interchangeably, and back-quotes for delimited identifiers.  But I recommend getting into the habit of using only single-quotes for strings, because it makes your SQL code more portable to other RDBMS vendors, and also more clear to anyone reading your code.

You should use query parameters, as @Mike B suggests.  This is easy and it's far more secure than interpolating variables into SQL expressions.

---

You can use `bindParam()` or you can supply a `$values` associative array to the `execute()` function.  Doing both is redundant.

Note that the array you give to the `execute()` method doesn't have to have the `:` character prepending the placeholder name:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE myfield = :myfield");
// both of the following would work:
$stmt->execute( array(":myfield" => $value ) );
$stmt->execute( array("myfield" => $value ) );
```

Also to support parameters in both the `SET` clause and the `WHERE` clause, I'd suggest that you distinguish the fields when you specify the parameter placeholder names.  That way if you reference the same field in both clauses (one to search for an old value, and the other to set a new value), you won't conflict.

Perhaps `":set$field"` in the `SET` clause, and `":where$field"` in the `WHERE` clause.

---

**update:** I have tested the following code.  First, I use plain arrays, instead of the CachingIterator you used.  I don't need to use the `hasNext()` method since I'm using `join()`.

```
$settings = array("myfield" => "value");
$conditions = array("id" => 1);

$sql = "UPDATE $table SET \n";
```

Next is a demo of using `array_map()` and `join()` instead of loops.  I'm using PHP 5.3.0 so I can use inline closure functions.  If you use an earlier version of PHP, you'll have to declare the functions earlier and use them as callbacks.

```
$sql .= join(",",
    array_map(
        function($field) { return "$field = :set$field"; },
        array_keys($settings)
    )
);

if ($conditions)
{
    $sql .= " WHERE "
    . join(" AND ",
        array_map(
            function($field) { return "$field = :where$field"; },
            array_keys($conditions)
        )
    );
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

I couldn't get `bindParam()` to work, it always adds the value "1" instead of the actual values in my array.  So here's code to prepare an associative array and pass it to `execute()`:

```
$params = array();
foreach ($settings as $field=>$value) {
    $params[":set$field"] = $value;
}
foreach ($conditions as $field=>$value) {
    $params[":where$field"] = $value;
}

$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, I was already building 4 loops in one function, because I am not too familiar with this. I have to take a closer look though.

Comment: You can tighten up your code by using `array_map()` and `join()` instead of all those loops.

Comment: Thanks, you where faster, I never used those functions, so I will take a look at that also

Comment: If you could show a little example how array_map could be used to make it more efficient, that would be great. Do you mean to create an anonymous callback function to do the stmt->bindparam?

Comment: Ì have a problem with the code above, it does not give good results
If I do ':set'.$field and bind it with ':set'.$k then I will get the wrong value in the fields. I tested it by removing the set, but then I also needed to add the array to the execute(). So, I have to rethink it again.

Comment: the error I got is SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: It's indeed the bindParam() that is not working in this setup.
Those examples with array_map and join are great. I could not have come up with that right away. Very nice for future use.Also had some trouble calling the function from a class, because I thought I had to supply the parameter also, but it was just the function name.
All in all it came to the merger of two arrays. Thanks, Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's that, try to give you one point extra, it deducts it, sorry

Comment: LOL! Thanks, I'm not hurting for points.  :-)  I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PDO, why not use the `bindParam()` and `bindValue()` methods [demonstated here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)?

Comment: thanks, I will look into that, if that eliminates the problem

Comment: Can you also have more then one array with field/values?
One for the updates and one for the conditions.
Because if I see this-:$stmt->execute($values); then only one array that binds with the parameters is executed?